# Groovy/Java getting user variables on Windows machine

Tags: java, windows, groovy, environment-variables

We have:

```
System.getenv()
```

for getting the system variables (red arrow), but I can't figure how to get user variables (blue arrow)?

[image]

Comment: Aren't they both sets of environment variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From JVM point of view it doesn't matter whether you set a environment variable at system or user level.
They are merged by Windows anyway (specific user variables for specific user sessions, obviously).

The code to obtain value of such variable is `System.getenv("variablename")` and can look exactly the same either in Groovy or Java.

What can possible cause that your variable is null? After setting such variable you need to restart your application. It may be IDE, www server or whatever. JVM needs to be given an opportunity to pick up new variables (or new values of old variables) while initializes.

Simple test to check whether your variable is set for sure is to run windows console (cmd) and type `set`. This will print all available environment variables which includes user variables as well.

One more thing worth of mentioning is `PATH` variable which you point at in your example. Windows treats this one different than any other. Normally whenever you set user variable with the same name as already existing system variable it means that system value will be overwritten with user value for this user sessions.
With `PATH` variable, however, Windows appends system value with user value.

Anyway, you can't access system variable value for a given variable name if variable with the same name but different value is set at user level. It's already been overwritten or appended.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, both, the user specific and system-wide Path values were retrieved when querying `System.getenv("Path");`

Comment: SoapUI GUI should be restarted from my experiense, if you are scripting in this tool and the System/ User variable are created after starting it.